# Running all test scenarios with Sencha Test CLI

Tags: testing, jenkins, extjs, sencha-cmd, sencha-test

With Sencha Test I created some test scenarios and asking myself, whether it is possible to run several test scenarios via CLI on Windows command. I know that I can run a specific scenario with `stc run -p Embedded` within the scenario's folder or `stc run -p Embedded -s [SCENARIO_FOLDER]` outside the scenario folder.

Now what I'm wondering: Is it possible to run several test scenarios via CLI? I tried e.g. ANT-style `stc run **/* -p Embedded` or `stc run -p Embedded` in the parent folder, but nothing worked. When it comes to CI with Jenkins, it should be possible to run all test scenarios at once / in parallel - but how? I could not find any hint so far.

Or is it a misunderstanding of how Sencha tests should be organized, like having all integration tests in one scenario with several folders?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to run multiple scenarios with STC. I would suggest placing all related tests in one scenario if possible.